# Read, transform and stream to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, etl

I need to build a server that reads large csv data files (100GBs) in a directory, transforms some fields and streams them to a Hadoop cluster.

These files are copied over from other servers at random time (100s times/day). It takes a long time to finish copying a file.

I need to:

1. Regularly check for new files to process (i.e., encrypt and stream)
2. Check if a csv is completely copied over to kick off encryption
3. Process Stream multiple files in parallel, but prevent two processes
   to stream the same file
4. Mark files being streamed successfully
5. Mark
   files being streamed unsuccessfully and restart the streaming
   process.

My question is: is there an open source ETL tool that provide all of the 5, and works well with Hadoop/Spark Stream? I assume this process is fairly standard, but I couldn't find any yet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Flume](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/flume/) or [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) will serve your purpose. Both are well integrated with Spark and Hadoop.

Comment: Could you please explain how Flume and Kafka actually help us monitor incoming large files in this case? I had a quick look but it is more for streaming live data.

Comment: is this what you want?  https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the great library https://github.com/twitter/scalding. Maybe it can point you in the right direction :)